# Can't find TraceConfigruation reference (StackDriver ASP.Net setup)

Tags: asp.net, stackdriver

I'm following the setup instructions for Setting up StackDriver Trace for C# ASP.NET. In the section "Configuring the client library", step 3:
In the `Global.asax.cs` file's `WebApiApplication` class add teh following Init code block to initialize trace:

```
public override void Init()
{
    string projectId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["projectId"];
    // ...
    base.Init();
    TraceConfiguration traceConfig = TraceConfiguration
        .Create(bufferOptions: BufferOptions.NoBuffer());
    CloudTrace.Initialize(this, projectId, traceConfig);
}
```

The TraceConfiguration object doesn't exist in either of the client libraries referenced in step 2:

```
using Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNet;
using Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.Common;
```

I can't find any reference to this object, and doesn't appear to be built-in to the .net framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using this:

https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/aspnet

If I'm following this correctly, I think the documentation is out-of-date and `TraceConfiguration` was replaced with `TraceOptions` some time ago:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/pull/1120

And:
[`TraceOptions`](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNet/api/Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.Common.TraceOptions.html)

I'll ping the folks on the PR and who contribute to this library, let's see whether I can get them to help you and -- if necessary -- correct the docs.

Comment: @ian-tunbridge we're confident the docs are incorrect. I have easiest access to (ASP).NET Core (on Linux) and it's more difficult for me to repro the issue (which I think requires ASP.NET on Windows). Are you able to try replacing `TraceConfiguration` with `TraceOptions`? Would you like to see Google document both .NET Framework and .NET Core solutions?

Comment: The steps in the documentation don't mention anything about either of these configuration objects. Upon closer examination of the example projects on github, I can see these classes. The fix you suggest works, but this is poor documentation. One might expect these objects to be included in the libraries referenced.

Comment: @ian-tunbridge pleased to hear it work and I agree the documentation needs to be improved. I'll ping the folks on the documentation team and provide them this feedback.